# Как в Matlab сделать результат кубического корня однозначным?

Tags: matlab

Почему в Matlab результат кубического корня может быть правильным, но не однозначным?
Например,

```
>> (-5-3)^(1/3)

ans =

   1.0000 + 1.7321i
```

А если сразу:

```
>> -8^(1/3)

ans =

    -2
```

Понятно, что в обоих случаях извлекается кубический корень из -8, но ответ-то разный, хотя и правильный в обоих случаях.

Как можно контролировать, какой результат нужно получить - комплексный или действительный?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос:
"Как можно контролировать, какой результат нужно получить - комплексный или действительный?"
пока не дан.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно [nthroot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nthroot.html) использовать для вычисления реального значения корня n-й степени.

Судя по [документации оператор A.^B](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) для отрицательного A и дробного B по модулю меньшего 1 всегда вернёт комплексное значение корня.

Если произошло, как вы описываете, то у унарного - приоритет ниже, чем у ^, сделайте так (-8)^(1/3) - и получите ожидаемый комплексный результат.

Comment: Где в документации написано, что у унарного - приоритет ниже чем у ^?

Comment: @abalckin, это доказывает ваш эксперимент.

Поищите, наверняка где-то отражено, однако эмпирического доказательства  достаточно. Или вы документацию на полноту проверяете?

Comment: @abalckin, глядите я [нашел][1]: 2 и 3 возведение в степень и унарный минус соответственно

  [1]: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/operators-and-elementary-operations.html

Comment: Ну и что? Пусть есть выражение (-8)^(1/3). По вашей ссылке на первом месте приоритета стоят (), поэтому это выражение должно быть эквивалентно -8^(1/3) и давать тот же результат.

Comment: Ну и вообще, если у меня в программе (m+n)^(1/3), причем (m и n) задает пользователь, как вообще узнать какой результат будет комплексный или действительный?